# LuaDate Metamethods Issue with Lua 5.1.4

Tags: lua, openwrt

i'm new in Lua and want to use LuaDate Library for my Project on a OpenWrt System.

It seems, that Metamethods not working correctly with Lua 5.1.4, which is the version 
installed in OpenWrt Backfire. If i try the following code with Lua 5.1.5 on osx:

```
date = require('date')
print(date('2013-12-14T00:07:04') < date('2013-12-14T12:07:01'))
```

true is printed. If i run the code on OpenWrt with LUA 5.1.4, a error is thrown:

```
lua: test.lua:3: attempt to compare two table values
    stack traceback:
    test.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Is it possible, to fix this issue? For example call the Metamethods directly?

Comment: I discovered, that it is possible to do a direct metamethod call with date().__lt(date1, date2). Nevertheless it is interessting to know, why this metamethod don't work like expected.

Comment: Is it possible that the openwrt version of lua got modified in such a way as to disable this metamethod? I would check the source and compare it against the reference implementation for differences.

Comment: you sure it is the same 'date' module that gets loaded? print(debug.getinfo(date.time)) in both environments (Lua 5.1.5 vs OpenWrt/Lua 5.1.4).

Comment: Dates in the format `2013-12-14T00:07:04` can be compared directly as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a table from the date lib, You can use `<` for nothing but numbers. Better to get key names and value names of a simple date value to understand which members it has.

for k, v in pairs(date("2013-12-14T00:07:04")) do
    print("KEY: "..k..", VALUE: "..v)
end

After getting keys and values, you can use something like this:

```
local d = date("2013-12-14T00:07:04")
local num = 0
num = d.seconds
num = num + d.minutes * 60
num = num + d.hours * 3600
if (num < 1500) return end
```